# Выполнить запрос с помощью CActiveRecord

Tags: activerecord, yii

Подскажите, как сформировать следующий запрос средствами CActiveRecord?

```
SELECT good_id, attribute_id, group_concat(value) 
FROM good_has_attribute
GROUP BY attribute_id;
```

Comment: Такое не прокатит?

    $model->findAll(
        array(
            'select' => array('good_id', 'attribute_id', new CDbExpression('group_concat(value)'),),
            'group' => 'attribute_id',
        )
    );

Comment: Нет, к сожалению, колонка с `value` не извлекается вообще.

Comment: Получилось!! `new CDbExpression('group_concat(value) as value')`

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
Model::model()->findBySql(ваш запрос) где Model модель CActiveRecord
```